# How to reshape a matrix in Mahout Math?

Tags: math, matrix, mahout, reshape

All I need is a simple method or a function, something like like Matrix.reshape(rows, cols) - is there such thing in Mahout Math? What is a proper way to reshape a matrix there?

Answer (score 2):

There is a reshape method in Mahout math. What are you trying to do?

You may also be interested in the fact that Mahout 1.0-snapshot has an extensive linear algebra domain specific language (DSL) that is based loosely on R with a Scala base and unlike R works in a fully distributed manner on a Spark cluster.

- See this intro: [Mahout's Spark/Scala R-like DSL intro](http://mahout.apache.org/users/sparkbindings/home.html)
- The full docs are here: [Mahout's Spark/Scala DSL documentation](http://mahout.apache.org/users/sparkbindings/ScalaSparkBindings.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! The DSL looks really cool. Still, I cannot find the reshape method in Mahout Math. My code is in plain Java, and I have a dense matrix that I have to unroll into a row vector. In jBLAS (that I currently use), it's a single method call, `a.reshape(a.columns * a.rows, 1)`, but I do not see anything similar to `Matrix.reshape()` method in Mahout Math.